# Highest Common Factor to Infinity

Tags: arithmetic, infinity

Imagine you have a set of integers of x.For example:

7 9 11 13

Let us imagine that y is 1.

Then for each nth generation you added 1 to each member of the set, found the HCF of the set and set y to the HCF if it was bigger than y originally.

For example, when n was 9, the set would be:

16 18 20 22

and the HCF of the set would be 2.

Would there be a limit to y (the biggest HCF found) when n became infinity?

Comment: May I know the source of the problem?

Comment: The source of the problem is vague.It is more interesting merely as a problem to me.It is vaguely to do with working out a rule that ascertains for any cuboid, where a line passes from the top left corner to the bottom right, how many cubes the line would pass through (where a given cuboid is made up of a grid of 1x1 cubes). It was an extension I thought of in a maths class.

Comment: Sorry, if this is a silly question- or an obvious one.I am only 14 and have not yet had my curiosity crushed out of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let set $X$ be arranged in increasing order, and have elements $ x_1 < x_2 < \ldots < x_k$.

You are asking for

$$ \max_n HCF ( n + x_1, n+x_2, \ldots n+x_k)$$

Claim: This is equivalent to

$$ \max_n HCF ( n + x_1 , x_2 - x_1, x_3 - x_1, \ldots , x_k - x_1 )$$

Claim: This is equivalent to

$$ HCF ( x_2 - x_1, x_3 - x_1, \ldots , x_k - x_1 ).$$

Hence, there is a maximum, which is easily described.

Can you fill in the proofs of the claims yourself?

Comment: Ah, I nearly added that I thought it was to do with the differences.Thank you for the quick answer, though.